# Undefined Offset: 2

Tags: php, mysql

i have this Four Array, and i want it to be saved on Mysql using Foreach

**Success Execution:** after pressing the Submit button the data on the array are saved but there's an error

**Error:** *Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\Sample\index.php on line 10*

**Code:**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
$Array = $_POST['NOD'];
$Array2 = $_POST['Age'];
$Array3 = $_POST['DOB'];
$Array4 = $_POST['Relationship'];
$both_arrays = array_merge((array)$Array, (array)$Array1, (array)$Array2, (array)$Array3);
foreach(array_keys($both_arrays) as $i) {
 $sql="INSERT INTO sample_tbl(Col,Col1,Col2,Col3)VALUES('$Array[$i]','$Array1[$i]','$Array2[$i]','$Array3[$i]')";
 $result=mysql_query($sql,$con)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**it says Error on this line:**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sample_tbl(Col,Col1,Col2,Col3)VALUES('$Array[$i]','$Array1[$i]','$Array2[$i]','$Array3[$i]')";
```

**Database Result After Saving:** `

```
id Col Col1 Col2 Col3
1   11  11   11   11
2   22  22   22   22
3
4
5
6
7
8
(Auto) Null Null Null
```

There are 6 extra fields are being saved on the database starting from row 3 to 8
can you please help me figure out the problem here? and the problem for the Error on Line 10?

Comment: The `mysql_` family of functions will be removed from the language in the near future. You should switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: use empty() check before insert values

Comment: post your post form to get $_POST['NOD'];

Comment: @RakeshSharma if(empty(samplevariable)){then the mysql query here?}

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh instead of saving TWO rows only the result are 8 rows is there a way that i can check if the array is empty or not? i tried using EMPTY and $Array1 != "" but still there are extra rows being saved on the database

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error on line 10, you're *iterating* over `$both_arrays` to get the keys but you're attempting to *access* the elements in `$Array`, `$Array1` and so forth.

I think what you probably *meant* to write was:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sample_tbl(Col,Col1,Col2,Col3)VALUES
    '$both_arrays[$i]', '$both_arrays[$i]',
    '$both_arrays[$i]', '$both_arrays[$i]')";
```

I'd fix that first, it may well solve your dodgy data inserts as well.

Comment: it works however on my Array it only Contains Two Rows you can see from the example the inputs 11 and 22. In Addition the Data on the Array come from a dynamic input type so new rows can be added or deleted Example: 11 22 33 that is 3 rows or 11 1 row only can you please help me check the array if it is empty or not? i really appreciate the help thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
include('connection.php');
    if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
    $Array = $_POST['NOD'];
    $Array2 = $_POST['Age'];
    $Array3 = $_POST['DOB'];
    $Array4 = $_POST['Relationship'];

    foreach(array_keys($Array) as $i) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO      sample_tbl(Col,Col1,Col2,Col3)VALUES('$Array[$i]','$Array2[$i]','$Array3[$i]','$Array4[$i]')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$con)or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: Same Result, the output is the same as the Result i posted above on the database output

Comment: error on line foreach "Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\Sample\index.php on line 9" and "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\Sample\index.php on line 9"